# Deleting specific rows from a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with some US govt data which has a lengthy list of cities and zip codes.
After some work, the data is in the following format.

```
dat1 = data.frame(keyword=c("Bremen", "Brent", "Centreville, AL", "Chelsea, AL", "Bailytown, Alabama", "Calera, Alabama",
              "54023", "54024"), tag=c(rep("AlabamCity",2), rep("AlabamaCityST",2), rep("AlabamaCityState",2), rep("AlabamaZipCode",2)))
dat1
```

However, there are certain keywords which aren't properly working. So in the below example, there are two 'zip codes' which
are labeled as 'AlabamaCity' and 'AlabamaCityState'. For some reason, the original data set from the government has several zipcodes
which aren't properly grouped with the other zip codes.

```
dat2 = data.frame(keyword=c("Bremen", "Brent", "50143", "Chelsea, AL", "Bailytown, Alabama", "52348",
              "54023", "54024"), tag=c(rep("AlabamCity",2), rep("AlabamaCityST",2), rep("AlabamaCityState",2), rep("AlabamaZipCode",2)))
dat2
```

I wanted to know how I could iterate through the entire list of keywords and delete all the rows with numeric values (they're acctually saved as character
values) which don't have a 'AlabamaZipCode' tag. So the previous data should end up looking like.

```
dat3 = data.frame(keyword=c("Bremen", "Brent", "Chelsea, AL", "Bailytown, Alabama", "54023", "54024"), 
          tag=c(rep("AlabamCity",2), rep("AlabamaCityST",1), rep("AlabamaCityState",1), rep("AlabamaZipCode",2)))
dat3
```

The challange seems to be that there are certain numeric values which I want to keep and others which I want to delete.
Can anyone help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think two grepl expressions should do the trick:

```
> dat2[ !( grepl("City", dat2$tag) &  grepl("^\\d", dat2$keyword) ) , ]
             keyword              tag
1             Bremen       AlabamCity
2              Brent       AlabamCity
4        Chelsea, AL    AlabamaCityST
5 Bailytown, Alabama AlabamaCityState
7              54023   AlabamaZipCode
8              54024   AlabamaZipCode
```

You are  eliminating the rows where there are digits in `keyword` and "City" in `tag`

Answer (score 6):

It helps to store the data as characters, not factors:

```
dat2 <- data.frame(keyword=c("Bremen", "Brent", "50143", "Chelsea, AL", 
                             "Bailytown, Alabama", "52348", "54023", "54024"),   
                   tag=c(rep("AlabamCity",2), rep("AlabamaCityST",2), 
                         rep("AlabamaCityState",2), rep("AlabamaZipCode",2)),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE) ## note this bit
```

Now we can convert `keyword` to numeric, and if it isn't a number in character format, we get an `NA`:

```
want <- with(dat2, as.numeric(keyword))
```

which gives us this:

```
> (want <- with(dat2, as.numeric(keyword)))
[1]    NA    NA 50143    NA    NA 52348 54023 54024
Warning message:
In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

You can ignore the warning or suppress it, but don't use this casually as it can mask problems:

```
suppressWarnings(want <- with(dat2, as.numeric(keyword)))
```

The final step is to select the elements of `want` that are **not** `NA` **and** have `keyword` equal to `"AlabamaZipCode"`, which we do using `&`:

```
(!is.na(want) & (dat2$tag != "AlabamaZipCode"))
```

That selects the rows we don't want, so we need to negate the above, turning `TRUE` to `FALSE` and vice versa:

```
!(!is.na(want) & (dat2$tag != "AlabamaZipCode"))
```

Putting this together we have:

```
dat2[!(!is.na(want) & (dat2$tag != "AlabamaZipCode")), ]
```

which gives:

```
> dat2[!(!is.na(want) & (dat2$tag != "AlabamaZipCode")), ]
             keyword              tag
1             Bremen       AlabamCity
2              Brent       AlabamCity
4        Chelsea, AL    AlabamaCityST
5 Bailytown, Alabama AlabamaCityState
7              54023   AlabamaZipCode
8              54024   AlabamaZipCode
```

Full solution is:

```
want <- with(dat2, as.numeric(keyword))
dat2[!(!is.na(want) & (dat2$tag != "AlabamaZipCode")), ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one (slightly convoluted) approach that you may consider. First, create an identity column for each row. This will help with the subsetting. Secondly, create a vector of those id's that match your criteria. Finally, subset those id's out of your final data.

The data you posted defaults to factors, not character data so I've accounted for that. If that's different than your actual data, you'll have to adjust accordingly. Also, when I converted the data to numeric, NAs are generated. A warning message is generated, but we can ignore that for this bit.

```
#Generate an ID column
dat4$id <- 1:nrow(dat4)

#Create a vector of the id's that match your criteria'
outliers <- dat4[as.character(dat4$tag) != "AlabamaZipCode" & !(is.na(as.numeric(as.character(dat4$keyword)))) , "id"]

subset(dat4, !(id %in% outliers), select = 1:2)
             keyword              tag
1             Bremen       AlabamCity
2              Brent       AlabamCity
4        Chelsea, AL    AlabamaCityST
5 Bailytown, Alabama AlabamaCityState
7              54023   AlabamaZipCode
8              54024   AlabamaZipCode
```

Actually, you can shorten all of this to the following and avoid generating the id.

```
dat4[!(as.character(dat4$tag) != "AlabamaZipCode" & !(is.na(as.numeric(as.character(dat4$keyword))))) , ]
```