# Remove Rows From Data Frame where a Row matches a String

Tags: r, dataframe

I do I remove all rows in a dataframe where a certain row meets a string match criteria?

For example:

```
A,B,C
4,3,Foo
2,3,Bar
7,5,Zap
```

How would I return a dataframe that excludes all rows where C = Foo:

```
A,B,C
2,3,Bar
7,5,Zap
```

Comment: Related question: [Deleting specific rows from a data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601658/deleting-specific-rows-from-a-data-frame).

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Just use the `==` with the negation  symbol (`!`). If dtfm is the name of your data.frame:

```
dtfm[!dtfm$C == "Foo", ]
```

Or, to move the negation in the comparison:

```
dtfm[dtfm$C != "Foo", ]
```

Or, even shorter using `subset()`:

```
subset(dtfm, C!="Foo")
```

Comment: Or just `dftm[dtfm$C != "Foo", ]` which is the same but slightly more easier to read.

Comment: .. or `subset(dftm, C!="Foo")`

Comment: How would you do this with an arbitrary number of conditions? Like if you wanted to remove all rows where "C = Foo" or "C = Bar"?

Comment: That would be another question. But the key is to use %in% and !. In your example !(C %in% c("Foo", "Bar"))

Comment: All good feedback. To complete Luciano's suggestion for the non-subset() example, I found that this worked to trim out undesired rows: dtfm <- dtfm[!(dtfm$C %in% c("Foo", "Bar")),]     Just be sure not to forget the trailing comma in the [] brackets.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `dplyr` package to easily remove those particular rows.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- filter(df, C != "Foo")
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a column(A) in a data frame with 3 values in it (yes, no, unknown). I wanted to filter only those rows  which had a value "yes" for which this is the code, hope this will help you guys as well  --

```
df <- df [(!(df$A=="no") & !(df$A=="unknown")),]
```

Answer (score 1):

if you wish to using dplyr, for to remove row "Foo":

```
df %>%
 filter(!C=="Foo")
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered but here is another option:

```
library (dplyr)
df %>% filter(!c=="foo)
```

###### OR

```
df[!df$c=="foo", ]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If your exclusion conditions are stored in another data frame you could use [`rows_delete`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/rows.html):

```
library(dplyr)

removal_df <- data.frame(C = "Foo")

df %>% 
  rows_delete(removal_df, by = "C")

  A B   C
1 2 3 Bar
2 7 5 Zap
```

This is also handy if you have multiple exclusion conditions so you do not have to write out a long `filter` statement.

Note: `rows_delete` is only available if you have dplyr >= 1.0.0