# Subset data frame based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

[image]

I wish to filter a data frame based on conditions in several columns. For example, how can I delete rows if column A = B and Column E = 0.

Comment: It is not a good idea to alter Q like this -- older answers get invalidated and it brings confusion. Try asking new question in the future.

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650510/remove-rows-from-data-frame-where-a-row-match-a-string

Answer (score 339, accepted):

Logic index:

```
d<-d[!(d$A=="B" & d$E==0),]
```

Comment: I tried so many complicated answers -- none worked. Your solution is simple and brilliant.

Comment: Actually, a simpler way of viewing it is: `foo.isolated <- subset(foo, !(sid == "sid104" & game.num == 7))`

Comment: Why are NA's still included

Comment: NA's killed my two hours :D
Note that it will also select NA's

Answer (score 100):

Subset is your safest and easiest answer.

```
subset(dataframe, A==B & E!=0)
```

Real data example with mtcars

```
subset(mtcars, cyl==6 & am!=0)
```

Comment: a good second example would be to filter on a list of values. ie subset of mtcars for cyl not in c(100, 200, 500)

Answer (score 2):

Use the which function:

```
A <- c('a','a','b','b','b')
B <- c(1,0,1,1,0)
d <- data.frame(A, B)

r <- with(d, which(B==0, arr.ind=TRUE))
newd <- d[-r, ]
```

Comment: -1. Don't use `which` for this.  Change the condition to `B==2` and see if it gives the answer that you want. See, e.g., http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips:surprises:traps#negative_array_indices

Comment: Why not to use `which` from [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html): "there are two important differences. First, when the logical vector contains `NA`, logical subsetting replaces these values by NA while `which()` drops these values. Second, `x[-which(y)]` is not equivalent to `x[!y]`: if `y` is all `FALSE`, `which(y)` will be `integer(0)` and `-integer(0)` is still `integer(0)`, so you’ll get no values, instead of all values. In general, avoid switching from logical to integer subsetting unless you want, for example, the first or last TRUE value."