# Dropping rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame which has multiple rows and columns

```
Data       C1         C2         C3 
R1     12         33         11
R2     11         2           0
R3      3         3           0
R4      2         3           1
```

and so on..

How can i drop all the rows from the data frame for which the C3 values are non zero?

The output data should look like

```
Data       C1         C2         C3
R2     11         2           0
R3      3         3           0
```

Comment: Look at `dplyr`package (functions `filter` for rows and `select` for columns)

Comment: The answer is already posted on stackoverflow, give a look to this post, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005154/conditionally-remove-dataframe-rows-with-r

Comment: This is a super basic R process. You do not need any packages. See the dupe links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I. Using R Basics

```
  df <- data.frame(Data=c("R1","R2","R3","R4"),C1=c(12,11,3,2),C2=c(33,2,3,3),C3=c(11,0,0,1))
  df
  #   Data C1 C2 C3
  # 1   R1 12 33 11
  # 2   R2 11  2  0
  # 3   R3  3  3  0
  # 4   R4  2  3  1

  df[df$C3 != 0,]
  #   Data C1 C2 C3
  # 1   R1 12 33 11
  # 4   R4  2  3  1
```

II. Using `dplyr` package's pipe operator `%>%` and `filter()` function

```
 library(dplyr)
 df %>% 
 filter(C3 != 0)
 #       Data C1 C2 C3
 #     1   R1 12 33 11
 #     2   R4  2  3  1
```

Answer (score 0):

`x[x$C3==0,]` should do the trick:

```
> x
   C1 C2 C3
R1 12 33 11
R2 11  2  0
R3  3  3  0
R4  2  3  1

> x[x$C3==0,]
   C1 C2 C3
R2 11  2  0
R3  3  3  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` from `dplyr`

```
df <- 
  df %>% 
  filter(C3 == 0)

Source: local data frame [2 x 4]

   Data    C1    C2    C3
  <chr> <int> <int> <int>
1    R2    11     2     0
2    R3     3     3     0
```

to reproduce your output data , however you asked

> How can i drop all the rows from the data frame for which the C3 values are non zero?

in which case the code is

```
df <- 
  df %>% 
  filter(C3 != 0)

Source: local data frame [2 x 4]

       Data    C1    C2    C3
      <chr> <int> <int> <int>
    1    R1    12    33    11
    2    R4     2     3     1
```

Comment: Damn, **Sowmya S. Manian** beat me to it :)

Comment: Well, I was at your place months ago, started catching up. Sorry :) Keep learning!!

Comment: :)  just learning - but it's all good!

Comment: Good to know. Have a great day ahead!!!

Comment: How come you have 0 in quotes in `C3 != "0"`, is it working with quotes also Just curious, because we put quotes only for strings/characters.

Comment: No reason, just force of habit, I agree - should work with numeric data too. That's the beauty of R - many different ways to do the same operation :)

Comment: Hey it does not work when you put `C3 != "0"`, it works only when you put `C3 != 0` Please edit it. I just tried.

Comment: Ah, well spotted! Thanks, I'll edit the post :o

Comment: Hey sorry, its weird its working. But ideally it should be without quotes unless it is character in the first place.

Comment: Yes, it is odd isn't it - I agree though, for good practice should use quotes for characters and non-quoted for numeric data :)