# Making simple function to clean up data (removing rows conditionally without NA)

Tags: r

Hi I have animal abundance data collected from quadrats with 4 quadrats per station.

In the field, some quadrats were missed.

ex

```
St/ Q /Anim1 abundance /Anim 2 abundance/....etc
1 /1 /
1 /2 /
1 /3 /
1 /4 /
2 /1 /
2 /2 /
2 /4 /
3 /1 /
3 /2 /
3 /3 /
3 /4 /
```

Station 2 is missing quadrat 3. I would like to remove all rows (including animal abundance data) associated with station 2 from further analysis. I would like to do this in a function as I have multiple large csv files I need to clean up.

I tried subset and for loops but struggling with both

Thank you for your time

******update I'm working with this qc_Large29 <- Large29[Large29[, 5]>=4,]

which gives me all the 4th quadrats from each station. Is there a way to add a length() to it so that the new dataframe will only be the data associated with stations that have 4 quadrats?

**********update

```
 dput(Large29[1:30,1:5])
structure(list(FID = 652:681, areaContro = c(29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L
), areaShortN = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "CAIIN", class = "factor"), station = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L), quadrat = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L)), .Names = c("FID", 
"areaContro", "areaShortN", "station", "quadrat"), row.names = c(NA, 
30L), class = "data.frame")
>
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you could post a minimal example of your dataframes, e.g. using `dput( your.data )`.

Comment: It's too long by over 60k characters, but here's a couple excepts.. what are you interested in, maybe I can answer?   ("FID", 
"areaContro", "areaShortN", "station", "quadrat", "latitude", 
"longitude", "depthFatho", "surveyDTTM", "updatedPK", "surveyRawD", 
"cameraCont", "imageExist", "isImageOfI", "sand", "sandRipple", 
"shellDebri", "silt", "gravel",  
"scallops", "clappers", "seed", "seaStars", "crabs", "hermitCrab", 
"echinoderm", "lobster", "sandDollar", "ad", "anemone", "bHydra",

Comment: 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0), herring = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L,

Comment: subset your data so that it still contains examples of the rows you want to remove, e.g. by `dput(yourdata[1:30,])` .

Comment: My dataset is still too big to fit here even with 1:2

Comment: The problem is that I was unclear with my dataset description?

Comment: The answer will depend on the class of yor data. if this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005154/conditionally-remove-dataframe-rows-with-r?rq=1) doesn't help, you will need to create a minimal example (`dput(yourdata[1:30,1:5])`).

Comment: Updated my question, still too long to fit in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This selects everything but the "2" stations:

```
Large29[Large29$station!=2,]
```

for you second question (the edit), I would suggest to use dplyr, where you can group by stations:

```
library(dplyr)
Large29 %>% group_by(station) %>% filter(n()>=4) %>% as.data.frame()
```

Comment: No worries, welcome to SO! Please also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.