# Possible to use both "or" and "and" to select rows based on column values in df?

Tags: r, dataframe

I know how to select rows in a dataframe based on the values of two columns (using code from accepted answer on this question: [Conditionally Remove Dataframe Rows with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005154/conditionally-remove-dataframe-rows-with-r))

My dataframe looks like this (simplified):

```
Date        Afd  Count
2012-03-23  12   0
2012-03-23  16   10
2012-03-23  17   12
2012-03-27  12   3
2012-03-27  16   9
2012-03-27  13   7
2012-03-27  22   5
2012-04-05  12   11
2012-04-05  23   8
```

Now I use this code:

```
df <- df[!(df$Afd=="12" & df$Date=="2012-03-23"),]
```

But I also want to drop another Afd and another Date. Following this logic:
if Afd = 12 or 16, and Date = 2012-03-23 or 2012-03-27, then delete row.

Do I have to repeat this line 4 times with the different combinations or is there a better solution? (I suspect the latter)

Comment: You mean this `df[!(df$Afd %in% c(12, 16) & df$Date %in% c("2012-03-23", "2012-03-27")),]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add or statements with `|` or use `%in%`

```
df <- subset(df, !(Afd %in% c("12", "16") & 
                   Date %in% as.Date(c("2012-03-23", "2012-03-27"))
                  )
            )
```

Comment: Yup. Exactly the same as my comment!

Comment: I'm having problems with the date part though (this column is in actual date format). It doesn't react on it. If I run this code `df[!(df$Date %in% c("2013-03-11","2013-03-19")),]` nothing is removed. With this code `df[!(df$Date=="2013-03-11"),]
df[!(df$Date=="2013-03-19"),]` the correct rows are deleted. What am I missing?

Comment: @Tingolfin This is probabaly because of string to date conversion. Maybe `df$Date %in% as.Date(c("2013-03-11","2013-03-19")))` will work. If so, I will update my answer. @Sotos. Sorry, I actually updated my answer based on your comment to omit nested `& / |` calls.