# How do I completely delete a row with an empty cell in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, removeall, blank-line

I have an empty cell, but I want to delete it, even if there are cells (Even if it contains data) in the same row. As shown in the picture.

```
textparcali$word[!apply(textparcali$word == "", 1, all),]

Error in apply(textparcali$word == "", 1, all) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

[image: Screen capture]

821,824,833. I'm looking for a way to completely delete these lines. Thanks

Comment: use na.omit(textparcali)

Comment: Or something like `textparcali[!is.na(textparcali$word ),]` if you want to check the NAs on only that column.

Comment: Can also be done with `dplyr`: `textparcali %>% filter(!is.na(word))`

Comment: `textparcali[textparcali$word != "", ]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rui Barradas, Your suggestion solved the problem.

```
textparcali<-textparcali[textparcali$word !="",]
```

The same problem already existed as another issue. But they offered a different solution, and it worked.
[Link is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005154/conditionally-remove-dataframe-rows-with-r)