# How can I extract non-consecutive rows from a data set in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a 5 columns-1000+ rows data, I extracted specific lists from this data, based on "Student" which varies 1 to 13, and now I should simplify these lists. 
I want to extract non-consecutive rows from this data, for example, the 23rd, the 31st, the 38th.
How can I do that ?

Thanks

```
         School Time      Student   Classroom  Note
 23          1  212           1      2           22
 30          1  256           2      2           21
 31          1  257           3      2           27
 37          1  267           4      2           45
 38          1  269           5      2           14
 43          1  276           6      2           42
 44          1  278           7      2           13
 47          1  285           8      2           11
```

Comment: Try `dat[c(23, 31, 38), ]`

Comment: Note that you can subset based on conditions, too. That is probably more useful for a 1000+ row data.frame. I recommend reading an introduction to R.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you google your question before asking here? I mean this is *really* basic.

Comment: @ Andrie : It works, but I just don't know how to select all those rows
@ Roland : I read, but I'm little bit slow, sorry. 
@ Backlin : Yeah I googled it Backlin.

Comment: What is the criterion for selecting the rows 23, 31, and 38? Are these the row names or the row numbers?

Comment: @Sven : Consecutive rows end at those rows. For example, Row30, Row31, and suddenly it jumps to Row37. I just find to find that last row [ in this case Row31 ] before the jump. I have 1000+ rows in the data.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove Rows From Data Frame where a Row match a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650510/remove-rows-from-data-frame-where-a-row-match-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to select all rows where the difference between the (numeric) rowname and the rowname of the succeeding row is bigger than one:

```
 dat <- read.table(text = "School Time      Student   Classroom  Note
 23          1  212           1      2           22
 30          1  256           2      2           21
 31          1  257           3      2           27
 37          1  267           4      2           45
 38          1  269           5      2           14
 43          1  276           6      2           42
 44          1  278           7      2           13
 47          1  285           8      2           11", header = TRUE)


dat[c(diff(as.numeric(rownames(dat))) > 1, TRUE), ]
```

*Note*. This also selects the last row (`47`). If you want to exclude the last row, replace `TRUE` with `FALSE`.

The result:

```
   School Time Student Classroom Note
23      1  212       1         2   22
31      1  257       3         2   27
38      1  269       5         2   14
44      1  278       7         2   13
47      1  285       8         2   11
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i <- 3

DF2 <- DF[seq(from=i, to=nrow(DF), by=4),]
```

Extracts 3rd row and next onwards extracts 3+4=7th, 7+4=11th, 11+4=15th, so on....