# R Data Frame. Show All Columns that Match a Specific Word

Tags: r

First off I would like to say I am very new to R, about 2 weeks old. I am not sure the best way to phrase this but I have a table, consisting of 4 columns and 6 rows. I would like to pull all rows that match a word in a specific field.

```
Opened Created_by ticket closed
5/11   John Doe   773    TRUE
5/11   Jane Doe   774    FALSE
5/11   Jack Doe   775    TRUE
6/1    John Doe   805    TRUE
6/1    John Doe   806    FALSE
6/1    Jane Doe   807    TRUE
```

I want to see all the Tickets created by John Doe, so it would look something like this after I entered the correct code.

```
5/11 John Doe 773 TRUE
6/1  John Doe 805 TRUE
6/1  John Doe 806 FALSE
```

Comment: [Try something. Put forth some effort.](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove Rows From Data Frame where a Row match a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650510/remove-rows-from-data-frame-where-a-row-match-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data frame is named "dat":

```
dat[dat$Created_by == "John Doe",]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
subset(x = dat, subset = Created_by == "John Doe")
```

See also [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you are looking for but if you want general approach that allows your to match one or more than one then you can use `%in%`. Assuming mydata if your dataframe:

```
myword<-c("John Doe", "Jane Doe")

mydata[mydata$Created_by %in% myword,]
```

Example using iris data:

```
myspecies<-c("setosa","versicolor")
mydata<-iris
mydata[mydata$Species %in% myspecies,]
```