# R Labeling multiple date periods in a POSIXlt date sequence

Tags: r, date, posixct

I am working in R. I have a date sequence and I would like assign whether each particular date is term time or a school holiday. I plan to do this using a dataframe column where each row is labelled "Holiday" or "Term"

My approach is to create a time sequence and individually specify each holiday dates using a vector; the first element is the start date of the holiday and the second is the end of the holiday.

I then create an if-or statement to test whether the time lies within any of the holiday dates specified in the vectors.

Here is my code so far:

```
start <- as.POSIXlt("2015-10-10 00:00:00")
end <- as.POSIXlt("2016-03-31 00:00:00")

DateSeq <- seq(from=start, to=end, by="mins")

#Holidays defined using a vector with by start and end date

H1 <- c("2015-10-26", "2015-11-3") #October half term
H2 <- c("2015-12-16", "2016-01-05") #Christmas holiday
H3 <- c("2016-02-15", "2016-02-19") #Feb half term 
H4 <- c("2016-03-24", "2016-03-31") #Easter holiday 

date_table <- data.frame(Time = DateSeq)

if ((round(date_table$Time, units = "days")== H1[1] <> H1[2]) |         (round(date_table$Time, units = "days") == H2[1] <> H2[2])) {
  date_table$Holiday <- "Holiday"
 } else {
  date_table$Holiday <- "Term"
}
```

As you can see this code does not work and simply labels all the rows as "Term".

Therefore I am wondering the following:

1. How I can specify the date range in the holiday vectors so it can be used within the if statement?
2. Whether this is the best approach to use? I am quite new to R and I was thinking of alternatives such as creating a set of individual sequences for term and holidays and then stitching them together. This approach however seems fiddly but would appreciate your thoughts.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to your approach by avoid `if-else`.

```
# Or alternatively by="mins"
DateSeq <- seq(from=start, to=end, by="hours")
date_table <- data.frame(Time = DateSeq)

# Put all holidays together
H<-rbind(H1,H2,H3,H4)

# Or alternatively set to "Term"
date_table$Holiday<-0

# Assign all the holidays
for (i in 1:nrow(H)){
  date_table[date_table$Time > H[i,1] &  date_table$Time < H[i,2],"Holiday"]<-1 # or "Holiday"
}

# Check they are correctly assign
plot(date_table)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works really well however the last day of the holiday remains labelled as Term. I have tried replacing the < with <= and [i+1,2] and H[i,2]+1, but the I cannot get the final specified holiday date to be labelled as holiday. Do you have any suggestions why this could be happening? Or should I just specify one extra day in the holiday vector? Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: You can change the `date_table$Time < H[i,2]` to `date_table$Time < as.POSIXlt(H[i,2])+86400` which essentially adds an extra day or you can add the extra day into your holiday vector.

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again but I was wondering if you knew a way of removing the row completely from the dataframe rather than adding a label? I tried using this solution [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650510/remove-rows-from-data-frame-where-a-row-match-a-string)  and used !data_table$Time but this did not work. Do you have a solution or know where I could find it? Thanks

Comment: Which row do you want to remove? Your question is unclear. There are several ways to index the row (http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame/data-frame-row-slice)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I finally found the solution to delete the rows: This is what I was trying to achieve: `for (i in 1:nrow(H)){
  date_table <- date_table[!(date_table$Time > H[i,1] &  date_table$Time < as.POSIXlt(H[i,2])+86400),]
}`

Comment: I just noticed another problem with this approach, there is a slight overlap and the first minute is labelled as Term when it was specified as Holiday. For example 26/10/2015 is specified as a Holiday, however, the first minute - 26/10/2015 00:00 is  labelled as Term and then 26/10/2015 00:01 is listed as Holiday as expected. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Change `date_table$Time > H[i,1]` to `date_table$Time >= H[i,1]` should take care of it.

Comment: Oh thank you so much for your help. Turned out to be an easy change. I spent all day on it but could not see it. In the end I had to change the first term to Posixlt also and used `for (i in 1:nrow(H)){
  date_table <- date_table[!(date_table$Time >= as.POSIXlt(H[i,1])  &  date_table$Time < as.POSIXlt(H[i,2])+86400),]
}` Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `cut()` to cut DateSeq into term and holiday.

```
res <- cut(DateSeq, breaks = as.POSIXlt( c(H1, H2, H3, H4), format = "%Y-%m-%d"), labels = c("October", "term1", "Christmas", "term2", "Feb", "Term3", "Easter"))
table(res)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems this solution splits the date sequence into each term and then counts the minutes. How could I then enter this information into a dataframe?

Comment: the table is just to show that `cut` has worked. What do you want entering into a data.frame?