# How can I exclude values from a dataset?

Tags: r

Basically I have a data set with ages of male and females in a study, when the age is NA the number in the age column is 99. I need to be able to exclude all the 99's from the data set to then find other statistics from the data.

Comment: Subsetting a data frame is a pretty basic operation in R that should be covered by lots of tutorials and many questions on SO. I like the [Quick-R](https://www.statmethods.net/) tutorials as a place to start. Beyond that, see the guidance on making a [mcve] for a good question

Comment: Since this question has been reopened, the link to the post it was marked as a duplicate of is now gone. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6650510/5325862) it is again. It's got 3 answers with several options that should have your situation covered