# How to remove a specific row number from a data frame in r

Tags: r

Let say I want to remove fifth, eighth, and 25th row from a data frame, how can I do so? I was trying `dt[!c(5,8,25), ]` but it doesn't work. Suggestions please. Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601658/deleting-specific-rows-from-a-data-frame?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for `-` not `!`:

```
mydf <- data.frame(matrix(1:12, ncol = 2))
mydf[-c(1, 3, 4), ]
#   X1 X2
# 2  2  8
# 5  5 11
# 6  6 12
```